# Laravel Sum a Collection with multiple items

Tags: laravel

I have a model `SettlementEntries` that has a relation to a sub table `return $this->hasMany('App\Online', 'entry_id');`

When trying to fetch one single Entry i'm able to sum my collection like in the example below.

```
$item = SettlementEntries::find($id);
$item->Online->sum('field'); // returns the correct sum
```

My problem starts when the `$id` is an array, so my result contains 2 SettlementEntries.

```
 $items = SettlementEntries::find($ids);
 $items->Online->sum('field'); <- returns zero
```

What is the correct way to retrieve those sums?

Comment: use `foreach` to work with single entry

Comment: I don't nee the sum of a single entry, I need them combined.

Answer (score 7):

Laravel's `Collection` makes this very easy, by using *dot notation*. Some examples [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#arrays).

**The simple way (dot notation):**

```
$sum = $items->sum('Online.field');
```

**More explicit (callback):**

Or, if you want to be more explicit, e.g. using conditions/filters: *provide a `Closure`:*

```
$sum = $items->sum(function($item) {
  return $item->Online->sum('field');
});
```

Comment: That works, but it is not possible to do this without looping over them?

Comment: `$sum = $items->sum('Online.field');` always returns 0

Comment: I've tested this on an array. Can you try `$sum = collect($items->toArray())->sum('Online.field');`?

Comment: Does not work Jan. Keep getting 0 as a result. If I do the following `$items->sum('Online.0.field');` it seems to work with your first solution (dot notation above).