# Collection sum fo array of obj Laravel whit relation callback

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I try to figure it out to make the sum of all the levelAccess for a role. 
this is my data:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "uuid": "1fdc0660-1b0f-11e8-b9e8-b5c43c94fc8c",
    "name": "admin",
    "total_levelAccess": null,
    "level_accesses": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "userRoleId": 1,
            "levelAccess": 6,
            "code": "location"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "userRoleId": 1,
            "levelAccess": 6,
            "code": "business"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "userRoleId": 1,
            "levelAccess": 6,
            "code": "account"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "userRoleId": 1,
            "levelAccess": 6,
            "code": "review"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "uuid": "1fdc2980-1b0f-11e8-a6e9-7934303e6543",
    "name": "editor",
    "total_levelAccess": null,
    "level_accesses": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "userRoleId": 2,
            "levelAccess": 6,
            "code": "location"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "userRoleId": 2,
            "levelAccess": 2,
            "code": "business"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "userRoleId": 2,
            "levelAccess": 2,
            "code": "account"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "userRoleId": 2,
            "levelAccess": 6,
            "code": "review"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my code :

```
$userRoleWithLevel = UserRole::with('levelAccesses')->get();

$userRoleWithLevel->map(function ($userRole) {
$$userRole->total_levelAccess = $userRole->level_accesses->sum(function ($levelAccesses) {
return $levelAccesses->levelAccess;
});
return $userRole;
});

and 

$userRoleWithLevel->map(function ($userRole) {
    $userRole->total_levelAccess = $userRole->level_accesses;
                return $order;
});
```

I got an error

```
FatalThrowableError in ApiSystemController.php line 49:
Call to a member function sum() on null
```

I can't access to level_access.

I tried this answered

[Laravel Sum a Collection with multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928501/laravel-sum-a-collection-with-multiple-items)

we use Laravel 5.2

Please if somebody can help me.

my UserRole model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use App\Models\LevelAccess;

class UserRole extends Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'userRoles';
    protected $connection = 'system';
    protected $fillable = [
        'uuid',
        'name'
    ];

    public function levelAccesses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LevelAccess::class, 'userRoleId','id');
    }

// I try this but it doesn't work to.
    public function sumlevelAccesses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LevelAccess::class,'userRoleId','id')
            ->selectRaw('SUM(levelAccess) as total_Level')
            ->groupBy('userRoleId');
    }
}
```

Comment: In your first map closure: What's the result of `dd($userRole->level_accesses);`?

Comment: dd($userRole->level_accesses); give me null, but i don't understand why print_r($userRoleWithLevel->toJson()); give the result i but in my question.

Comment: Can you add the code of your `UserRole` model?

Comment: Thanks @JonasStaudenmeir for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I found what was wrought. It's $userRole->**Level_accesses** it's the under score.

```
$userRoleWithLevel->map(function ($userRole) {
                    $userRole->total_levelAccess = $userRole->*levelAccesses*->sum(function ($level_Accesses) {
                        return $level_Accesses->levelAccess;
                    });
                    return $userRole;
                });
```

After that my result it's what i try to do.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "uuid": "1fdc0660-1b0f-11e8-b9e8-b5c43c94fc8c",
        "name": "admin",
        "total_levelAccess": 24,
        "level_accesses": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "userRoleId": 1,
                "levelAccess": 6,
                "code": "location"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "userRoleId": 1,
                "levelAccess": 6,
                "code": "business"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "userRoleId": 1,
                "levelAccess": 6,
                "code": "account"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "userRoleId": 1,
                "levelAccess": 6,
                "code": "review"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Thank you @Jonas Staudenmeir

Comment: hi @MehravishTemkar can you accept my answer for me ?

Comment: just click on the checkmark next to your answer, only the one who asks question can accept answer for it